# If $\ker T=${$0$}, then $T(0)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

I want to prove that:

Let $T:V \to W$ be a linear transformation such that $\dim \ker T = 0$ than $ \left \{ v_1,v_2,...,v_k \right \}\subseteq V $ is Linear Independent $\Leftrightarrow \left \{ T(v_1),T(v_2),...,T(v_k) \right \}\subseteq W $ is Linear Independent.

The left to right side I have done, and I left with the reverse side:

Assume $\left \{ T(v_1),T(v_2),...,T(v_k) \right \}\subseteq W $ is Linear Independent,

And let $c_1,c_2,...,c_k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...+c_kv_k=0$.

So $T(c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...+c_kv_k)=T(0)$ which means $c_1T(v_1)+c_2T(v_2)+...+c_kT(v_k)=T(0)$.

We know that $\dim \ker T = 0$, so $\ker T=\left \{ 0 \right \}$, than is that correct to say that $T(0)=0$ ?

If yes than $c_1T(v_1)+c_2T(v_2)+...+c_kT(v_k)=0$, and since $ \left \{ T(v_1),T(v_2),...,T(v_k) \right \}\subseteq W $ is Linear Independent, that means $c_1=c_2=...=c_k=0$, so $ \left \{ v_1,v_2,...,v_k \right \}\subseteq V $ is Linear Independent.

Thanks!

Comment: If $T$ is a linear transformation then $T(0) = 0$ regardless of its kernel.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always have $T(0)=0$ as

$$T(0) = T(0+0) = T(0) + T(0)$$ and therefore $T(0)=0$. This is true for any linear map whatever the kernel is.

*Based on that what you did to prove the right to left implication of the body of your question is correct.*

Comment: Thanks a lot! So my complete proof is ok?

Comment: It is way too complicated and also it adds a hypothesis that is not required.

Comment: Oh ok, how can I simplify it? Thanks again!

Comment: The confusion may be that the question in your title and body are not the same.  This answer appears to address the question in the title as do my comments.

Comment: Again the hypothesis $\ker T = \{0\}$ is useless. Just use the one-line proof of my answer that is true whatever $\ker T$ is.

Comment: @badjohn this is indeed a good comment!

Comment: Yes I understand that. Sorry for the confusion, regarding the proof in the body of my question, is it correct? Thanks !

Comment: What you did is indeed correct as you now know that $T(0)=0$ always!

Comment: Thank you so much! I won't forget it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> We know that $\dim \ker T = 0$, so $\ker T=\left \{ 0 \right \}$, than is that correct to say that $T(0)=0$ ?

$T(0)=0$ is always true whether $ker(T)=\{0\}$ or $ker(T)\ne\{0\}$. The correct proof of this doesn't depend on $dim\ker(T)$ either.

By linearity property,

$ T(cv)=cT(v), c\in$ field $F$ of scalars.
Put $c=0$ to get $T(0)=0$.